# How to fix Visual Studio 2008 freeze?

Tags: freeze, visual-studio-2008

My Visual Studio 2008 freezes under some conditions. After a restart all is fine at first, but once it starts updating IntelliSense and counting down items it stops always on the same number (the number slightly changed with further changes in the project). After that I get a sure freeze for:

- right-click in the code to get a context-menu
- changing the Build-Target from Debug to Release and vice versa
- quitting visual studio

After a freeze I have to kill the process. Any idea what is wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

If intellisense is hanging, it may be helpful to delete the ncb-file. It contains some data for Intellisense and is updated regularly.